# Heroku won't run latest python file

Tags: python, heroku

I use Heroku to host my discord.py bot, and since I've started using sublime merge to push to GitHub (I use Heroku GitHub for it), Heroku hasn't been running the latest file. The newest release is on GitHub, but Heroku runs an older version. I don't think it's anything to do with sublime merge, but it might be. I've already tried making a new application, but same problem. Anyone know how to fix this?

Edit: I also tried running Heroku bash and running the python file again

Comment: What do you mean you "use Heroku GitHub for it"? Did you just try `git push heroku master`?

Comment: I moved to Heroku CLI, but it still won't work.

Comment: "Heroku hasn't been running the latest file"—do you see the commit you expect to see if you run [`heroku releases`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#listing-release-history)?

Comment: Yes, I see the correct commit.

Answer (score 1):

1) Try to deploy branch (maybe another branch)

2) Enable automatic deploy